# Building a comma separated list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv

I'm tryin to use SQL to build a comma separated list of cat_id's

the code is:

```
declare     @output varchar(max)
set         @output = null;
select @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + convert(varchar(max),cat_id)
```

edit: changed '' to null, STILL same.
but the output im getting is like so:

```
, 66 , 23
```

the leading comma should not be there. What have i missed?

Answer (score 68):

Are you on SQL 2005? With props to [Rob Farley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144351/rob-farley) who showed me this just recently:

```
SELECT stuff((
    SELECT ', ' + cast(cat_id as varchar(max))
    FROM categories
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '');
```

The inside query (with `FOR XML PATH('')`) selects a comma-separated list of category IDs, with a leading ", ". The outside query uses the [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to remove the leading comma and space.

I don't have an SQL instance handy to test this, so it's from memory. You may have to play with the stuff parameters etc to get it to work exactly how you want.

Comment: I wanted to append to this answer - for a lot of STUFF statements you want the parameters to be 1 and 1, not 1 and 2 to create a truly comma-seperated list. Matt's answer uses 2 because he has a space after each comma. For more info, check out the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Answer (score 2):

COALESCE [Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

First argument `@output + ', '` is never null (unless you initialize `@output` as null AND set [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) to `ON`), so it's always returned.

Comment: +1 for the pointer to the ANSI property.  Use "select sessionproperty('CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL')" to see its current value; it is 1 by default, but if it's 0, it would cause the poster's COALESCE to fail.

Answer (score 1):

check `@output` value just before the execution of this query, I think it's not equal to `NULL` but to '' (empty string)

EDIT: (after the @auth edited the question)

now I'm sure it's '',

you have to initialize it to `NULL`

to do it independently of `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`, use the old `CASE WHEN`:

```
select @output = NULL
select @output = CASE WHEN @output IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @output+', ' END + value
```

Comment: even then `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` needs to be set to `ON`

Answer (score 1):

And sometimes...

you have to answer your own question

```
declare     @output varchar(max)
select      @output = case when (@output is null) then '' else ', ' END + convert(varchar(max),cat_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare     @output varchar(max)

select      @output = coalesce
                      ( 
                          @output + ', ' + convert(varchar(max),cat_id), 
                          convert(varchar(max),cat_id)
                      )
from        yourTableHere

print       @output
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution on SQL Server 2017+ is:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(cat_id,', ')
FROM Category;
```

If you are using `GROUP BY`, you can use:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(cat_id,', ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY some_col )   
FROM Category
GROUP BY group_id;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize @output to an empty string?  COALESCE will only work if it's a NULL string.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is that @output is not null from start, but an empty string. Set @output to null before the loop (or if it's not used since it's declared just don't assign an empty string to it).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies exactly to what you're looking for, but I found this right at the same time I found your questions. I use the second solution with FOR XML PATH, which Matt Hamilton mentioned above. It's worked great for me.

**Concatenating Rows - By Carl P. Anderson, 2009/10/14**

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/67973/

Answer (score -3):

On Unix, the sqlminus command lets you merge SQL commands and other formatting:

```
% sqlminus "select ri || ',' ||name|| ',' || numports || ',' || ascii(OVRONSET) from sdfctigw.ivrgrp where GRP_BEP is not null;" | sort -h
1,COMO INTERNAL 2,700,90
7,LOADIVR,10,80
10,SPEECH_IVR_PROD,600,95
```