# how to convert rows of integers of a table to comma separated string in sql server

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I am trying to convert rows integers to comma separate string but it is giving an error like conversion failed.

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '134, ' to data type int.
```

I tried this query

```
declare @CategoryIDs varchar(100)
select @CategoryIDs = COALESCE(@CategoryIDs+', ','')+ Val from #table
```

and the table values are like this

```
#table

Val
134
135
136
```

and i want output like this `134,135,136`

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @CategoryIDs varchar(100)
select @CategoryIDs = COALESCE(@CategoryIDs+', ','')+ CAST(Val AS varchar(100)) from #table
```

There are a number of ways to do string concatenation in SQL Server.  This way works, but may or may not be optimally-performing for your particular use case.  In general, I've found that the FOR XML PATH method works best.  You can find a description of it here:

[Building a comma separated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564980/building-a-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Vals INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(134),
(135),
(136)

    declare @CategoryIDs varchar(100) = '';   --<-- Assign to Empty string 
                                                 -- Otherwise concatenating to
                                                 -- null will always return null.

SELECT @CategoryIDs = COALESCE(@CategoryIDs+', ','')+ CAST(Vals AS VARCHAR(10))
from @TABLE

SELECT STUFF(@CategoryIDs, 1,2,'')
```

The problem occurs when you try to concatinate an integer value to a string you need to convert that int value to varchar only then you can concatinate it to a string I have done this using CAST() function.

**Using FOR XML PATH**

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Vals AS VARCHAR(100))
              FROM @TABLE
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
             .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')
```