# Using comma separated integer as string in where clause inside sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a stored procedure in within which a column having comma separated values (`codeid`) like ('20045,20069,20079') is being used for where in clause inside sub query for a main select statement. I tried some work around but couldn't find proper solution.

This is my code:

```
    SELECT 
        CodeID, Name,
        Experience,
        (SELECT COALESCE(@CodeDescription + '', '', '''') + CAST([Description] AS varchar(100)) 
         FROM SynCode 
         WHERE CodeID IN (SELECT * 
                          FROM dbo.fnSplitString(codeid, ','))) AS [codeDescription]
    FROM   
        Code
WHERE CodeIdentity = 1
```

Here `SynCode` contains description for each code and `dnSplitString` is a function which converts the CSV integer string into table.

While executing the above statement I'm getting the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Since I need only one row to return I'm using COALESCE to separate values with comma

Edit:
I have

```
    CodeID as '20045,20069,20079'
    and Iam Expecinting row result as
20045,20069,20079|Marry|2 years|Finance, Retail, Sales
```

Edit: CodeID, Name, Experience is VARCHAR, and CodeID in SynCode is Int

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [FOR XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564980/building-a-comma-separated-list).

Comment: The message here couldn't be more clear. Your subquery returned more than 1 row. That would be the column you have there. BTW, a subquery as a column is almost always a bad idea. You should use a join instead. This is yet another reason why it is a bad idea to store delimited strings like this. If your data was properly normalized there would not be an issue here at all.

Comment: You'll either need to split the array into a table of values (preferable) or use dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange, Sub query actually returns a single csv row but query inside where in clause returns data in a table(which might be the cause for error). I agree using delimited string is bad idea but this is how data is provided.

Comment: Nope...If you have two rows in SynCode because codeid has two values you will get two rows back. That select statement does NOT generate a csv, on the contrary it is splitting a csv into rows. Hence the error message.

Comment: @SeanLange, shouldn't COALESCE address this by converting returned records into csv?

Comment: Nope. [`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) simply returns the first argument that is not null.

Comment: @R.Sharma The only thing `COALESCE` does is return the first non-`NULL` value.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Right. Any work around you can suggest?

Comment: @Santi gave you proper hint

Comment: I'm not sure what do you expect to get from the sub query, so it's kinda hard to give an answer.

Comment: Well, I'm expecting a record having description in csv along with csv CodeID

Comment: @R.Sharma Did you visit the link I provided you in the very first comment? If you're looking for a subquery that generates a comma-separated list, I strongly believe you'll find your answer there.

Comment: @Santi, Thanks for the link. I did tried the solution earlier but since the values should be in INT I'm getting conversion error

Comment: please give example data -- example in the tables example in the parameters and then expected results from your query.  THIS IS THE ONLY way we will be able to help you.

Comment: @Hogan, Updated in question

Comment: Most important, put table definitions, or at least wich columns they contain

Comment: ok but you don't tell us what is in the tables --where does this come from >>>>Marry|2 years|Finance, Retail, Sales<<< for example I could say your database has a table called table with one column and one row with this value and the solution is `select * from table` you need to tell us the data model and data contents of your system in order for us to have a clue how to answer your question to create that output.

Comment: Give an example of what dnSplitString( '20045,20069,20079' ) return. In which table is 'Description'. What is the purpouse of COALESE (in particular the third parameter seems useless considering the second is not null).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

> when the subquery is used as an expression.

You can't put the query in the Selectstatement because it return more than one element.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
    CodeID, Name,
    Experience,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(Description, ', ') 
     FROM SynCode 
     WHERE CodeID IN (SELECT * 
                      FROM dbo.fnSplitString(codeid, ','))) AS [codeDescription]
FROM   
    Code
WHERE CodeIdentity = 1
```

Let me know if it works.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm sure the OP does not want a cross join as a solution.  at least join on codeid.