# How to display data of multiple row into one string

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table named Skill which store the skills data.
the skill level '2337' is the Advanced , '2338' is the Intermediate, '2339' is the beginner .
I want to display the skills name data based on the skill level that looks like this
For example,
Technical Profile_ID = 33

Advanced = Javascript, SQL, C#

Intermediate = Php

Beginner = vb,Java

I'm new to VB, can anyone help me to solve this.I'm using VB.net and database Microsoft SQL

[image]

Comment: Please provide your tables structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
create table #temp (skillid int, technicalprofile_id int, skilllevel int, skillname varchar(50))
insert into #temp values 
(35, 21, 2339, 'Php'),
(36, 21, 2339, 'Laravel')

SELECT skilllevel, skillname = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + skillname
           FROM #temp b 
           WHERE b.skilllevel = a.skilllevel 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM #temp a where skilllevel = 2339
GROUP BY skilllevel
```

The output is as shown below

```
skilllevel  skillname
2339        Php, Laravel
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) aggregation function on SQL Server 2017 or newer:

```
select SkillLevel, STRING_AGG(SkillName, ', ') as SkillNames
from Skills
group by SkillLevel
```

If you are on older version, see how to use `FOR XML` clause in this question: [Building a comma separated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564980/building-a-comma-separated-list)
, but the code should look like this:

```
select SkillLevel, (SELECT stuff((
        SELECT ', ' + cast(SkillName as varchar(max))
        FROM Skills s2
        WHERE s2.SkillLevel = s1.SkillLevel
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, ''))
from Skills s1
group by SkillLevel
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014. The function is not available.

Comment: I edit the code a little bit to show the results for specific id, i get what I want but the problem is the first data is not showing the full text, it left out the first alphabet of the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT SkillLevel, 
    SkillName = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + SkillName from tblSkill b where TechnicalProfile_ID = '33' AND b.SkillLevel = a.SkillLevel
    For XML PATH('')),1,2, '')
    FROM tblSkill a 
    Group by SkillLevel
```

The output is like

```
   SkillLevel        SkillName
   2337              Javascript,SQL,C#
   2338              Php
   2339              Vb,Java
```