# How To Write a 'GROUP BY' query to get all the Roles assigned to User for a given applicatoin

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables **User** and **User_Roles**. A User can have multiple Roles.

**USER TABLE**

```
User_Id  User_Name
1        Edward  
2        John 
3        Mark
```

**USER_ROLES TABLE**

```
User_ID    Role
1          Admin
1          Writer
1          Form
2          Writer
3          Form
3          Writer
```

I want to write a query that gives me the following result

```
User_ID    User_Name   Role
1          Edward      Admin, Writer,Form
2          John        Writer
3          Mark        Form,Writer
```

I have tried using a `GROUP BY` and I know this is how I can get the result but I am just not doing it right.

```
SELECT COUNT(T0.[User_Id]),T0.[User_Name],T1.[Role]      
FROM  USER T0  
INNER JOIN  USER_ROLES T1 ON T0.User_ID = T1.User_ID  
GROUP BY  T0.[User_Name], T1.[Role]
```

I am using a `COUNT` for test purpose only because when I do a `GROUP BY` with an aggregate function , I get an error.

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564980/building-a-comma-separated-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (available starting SQL Server 2017):

```
SELECT u.User_ID, u.User_Name, STRING_AGG(r.Role, ',') AS Roles
FROM  user u  
INNER JOIN  user_roles r ON r.User_Id = u.User_Id
GROUP BY u.User_ID, u.User_Name
```

NB: you might want to order the aggregated strings so you do get predictable values, like:

```
STRING_AGG(r.Role, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.Role) AS Roles
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to us the FOR XML / STUFF trick :

```
  SELECT 
   U.USER_NAME,
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + UR.ROLE 
          FROM [USER_ROLES] UR
          WHERE UR.USER_ID = U.USER_ID
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [ROLES]
FROM [USER] U
GROUP BY U.USER_NAME, U.USER_ID
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

https://rextester.com/YLIJQ30828